# Location Block & FastCGI Proxy

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to work out the following configuration; to preface this, I have a working Nginx/PHP FastCGI implementation working on a server with a single ip address, no FQDN and/or DNS serving a single PHP-based web site/application. Now, I've got the same scenario regarding another server, the difference being the requirement to server multiple client sites (one being a Wordpress site). I'm also NOT an Nginx expert by any stretch of the imagination to date.

For an overview: 
Document root for the server block is `'/usr/share/nginx/html'`, the Nginx default. Serves up fine, not an issues from http://xxx.xxx.xxx.76. Now the requirement is to have clients enter into their browser address http://xxx.xxx.xxx.76/pmhs as an example. Their php-based site would then be served, and so on for http://xxx.xxx.xxx.76/client for any other sites to be configured and served.

The document root directory for these clients are in a standard CentOS 7 folder `'/srv'` where all clients are configured as having site content available in their `'/srv/www/{client}.production/public_html'` folder. Most of the configuration examples I've been able to dig up aren't really specific to this type of config, most if not all have some sort of server and/or dns involved making routing a bit more understandable (in my view at this juncture).

```
server {
    ## -------------------------------------------------
    #   define virtual server configuration
    ## -------------------------------------------------
    listen          80;
    server_name     localhost;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index       index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/default.access.log  main;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/default.error.log debug;
    rewrite_log     on;

    ## -------------------------------------------------
    #   default site / ip address 
    #     @ serve nginx welcome page
    ## -------------------------------------------------
    location = / {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    ## -------------------------------------------------
    #   favicon.ico location filter
    ## -------------------------------------------------
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    ## -------------------------------------------------
    #   do not serve hidden files
    ## -------------------------------------------------
    location ~ /\. { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

    ## -------------------------------------------------
    #   client website location block
    ## -------------------------------------------------
    location ~ ^\/(?<client>[\w-_]+) {
        # reset the document root for the client
        #root /srv/www/$client.production/public_html;
        alias /srv/www/$client.production/public_html;

        # set the port used for the clients fastcgi pool
        if ($client = "belmond") { set $port 9000; }
        if ($client = "freeboard") { set $port 9001; }
        if ($client = "pmhs") { set $port 9002; }
        if ($client = "vesta") { set $port 9003; }

        #return 200 $document_root$uri;

        # nginx pass to php fastcgi - serve client web
        #location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        #}
    }

    location @fastcgi_proxy {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(.*)$;
        set $orig_path $fastcgi_path_info;

        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

        fastcgi_pass                        127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index                       index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME       $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO             $orig_path;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED       $document_root$orig_path;
        set $temp                           "/var/lib/php/fpm/session";
        fastcgi_param TEMP                  $temp;

        fastcgi_read_timeout                500;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort         on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout             60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout                180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size                 8k;
        fastcgi_buffers     64              8k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size        256k;
    }

    ## -------------------------------------------------
    #   redirect server error pages 
    #     @ serve nginx static page(s) /50x.html
    ## -------------------------------------------------
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
}
```

I can capture the client location with a regex, but then it starts to get a little 'blurry' for myself regarding what to do next based on what I see happening. When I CURL to the base ip addy, it's what is expected, the Nginx 'welcome' page is returned.

Now when I a pass the same addy with a client name (with the return 200 $document_root$uri; uncommented), the document_url has been aliased correctly, but now I'm sort of at a momentary loss. Ultimately, I'd like to get all client sites configured proxied to the php-fpm fastcgi proxy for service (that would be why there's $port code defined, but not used as of yet).

Just looking for any direction, etc on how to clean this up and get it working properly while further educating myself on Nginx configuration in the process...

What the goal would be is this for the main ip address (*currently working per this config*) :

```
URL = xxx.xxx.xxx.76 or xxx.xxx.xxx.76/ 
[serve] /usr/share/nginx/html/(*.html) content
[from] root /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

(Need to determine how to serve up client sites from their server directory)

```
URL = xxx.xxx.xxx.76/pmhs or xxx.xxx.xxx.76/pmhs/ 
[serve] /srv/www/pmhs.production/public_html/(*.php) 
[from] root srv/www/pmhs.production/public_html; 

URL = xxx.xxx.xxx.76/acme or xxx.xxx.xxx.76/acme/ 
[serve] /srv/www/acme.production/public_html/(*.php) 
[from ] root srv/www/acme.production/public_html;
```

Does any of this makes sense? I think I'm pretty close, but I just don't know if that's the case or not.

Comment: From what you wrote and what you've done - everything looks correct. You've got the setup correct, the general idea is completely fine (proxy to a different fpm port depending on what you pulled from the `path`) and all you're left with is getting down nginx config syntax in order to pass the port variable depending on what's in the address bar. Looks fine to me.

Comment: From the cli 

$> curl http://xxx.xxx.xxx.76/pmhs

I receive a 301 reply from the server, get a line written to the access log, but not the error log. Conversely, from a browser url 

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.76/pmhs

I receive a 403 [Forbidden] reply from the server, get a line written to both the access and error logs. Here's the error line:

*4 directory index of "/srv/www/pmhs.production/public_html" is forbidden, client: xx.xx.xx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /pmhs/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.76"

There's an index.php file to display the standard phpinfo page. Ideas?

Comment: `directory index of "/srv/www/pmhs.production/public_html" is forbidden` have you checked the permission on the directory? it looks as if Nginx is not able to access that directory.

Comment: It's funky, man... 

I moved the fastcgi code into the client location block, put a slash at the end of 'alias' definition and I get '/srv/www/pmhs.production/public_html//pmhs/index.php' from 'return 200 $document_root$fastcgi_script_name' in the inner php location block. Remove the slash at the end of the 'alias' definition and I get the 'directory index of "/srv/www/pmhs.production/public_html" is forbidden' in the error log and a 403 web page rendering. I'm really scratching my head on this one...

But thanx for the reply...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the bottom line to correct this particular configuration was to change the file paths on the server after I noticed what was taking place in the 'client' location block. Here's the final config block code:

```
## -------------------------------------------------
#   client website location block
## -------------------------------------------------
location ~ ^\/(?<client>[\w-_]+) {
    # reset the document root for client sites
    root /srv/www;

    # nginx pass to php fastcgi - serve client web
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(.*)$;
        set $original_path $fastcgi_path_info;

        # set the port used for the clients fastcgi pool
        if ($client = "phms") { set $port 9000; }
        if ($client = "vesta") { set $port 9001; }

        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

        fastcgi_pass                        127.0.0.1:$port;
        fastcgi_index                       index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME       $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO             $original_path;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED       $document_root$original_path;
        set $temp                           "/var/lib/php/fpm/session";
        fastcgi_param TEMP                  $temp;

        fastcgi_read_timeout                500;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort         on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout             60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout                180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size                 8k;
        fastcgi_buffers     64              8k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size        256k;
    }
}
```

It really came down to, for brevity's sake, making a change in the document root's file paths based on the debugging values I was noticing. I could have gotten the original paths to work, but it would have required a real effort and we didn't have the time allotted - nor was I willing at this point to 'fight city hall' with nginx to get things to work with an internal client file system definition.

Bottom line, it's working... one note of significance for any php-fpm devs looking at this, it should be somewhat evident that the php-fpm pool file for each client requires the particular port used in the 'listen' parameter be mirrored in the config 'if' code for the $port variable below as well.

Thanx to everyone that felt the need to contribute for the input!